# Publishing TFS in the cloud

Tags: version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I've been testing TFS in the cloud, and have it all set up with a test project.  Not using Git currently.  My question is related to publishing to our remote server.  I have a drive mapped and connect over VPN, and publishing via file system works.  It appears that publishing occurs from my local solution, and not the solution in the central repository.  This allows files that are checked out to be published to production.  I had thought publishing would occur from the central repository, and only publish the files that are checked in.

Is the publishing process supposed to move the files from the central repo?  Or, am I doing something wrong?

If not, are there controls in TFS to only publish approved/tested production files, and only files that are checked in?  For example, prevent publishing and notify developer if files are checked out.

It's been a long time since I've used SCM, so bear with me.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: When you talk about publishing, do you mean the publish feature in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes.  And/or, simply the appropriate way to move approved files from the repo to dev/production, if Publish is not it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to investigate the build service built into TFS as this will let you generate builds using only the checked in source. A guide to doing this using the TFS cloud can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj721597.aspx).

Comment: Are you saying that the only way to ensure code from the central repo (not local) is pushed to dev/production servers is using the build service?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Using some form of automated build service is the only way I know of guaranteeing that your build it generated from the central repo's code.